# How to call a method only after another method completes in ViewDidLoad

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to make an app where at the start Object A begins to fades.

Immediately after Object A completely fades, I'd like Object B to begin to fade.

I tried putting the below code in the ViewDidLoad method but they both run at the same time. Any idea on how to make one run after the other starting after the initial load?

```
ObjectA.isHidden = false
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: { () -> Void in
         self.Fader.alpha = 0
        })

ObjectB.isHidden = false
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
         self.Intro.alpha = 0
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest them

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear,.allowUserInteraction], animations: { 
    self.fader.alpha = 0 
 }) { (fin) in 
      self.objectB.isHidden = false
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.Intro.alpha = 0
      }) 
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks - I'm having trouble understanding the nesting though. How would it look if I did three fades adding in a new ObjectC?

Answer (score 0):

Nesting an animation within the first animation's completion block is perfectly fine. 
But for grouping multiple animations, it's worthwhile to consider CAAnimation Groups.

[here's](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1746-how-to-create-a-complex-loading-animation-in-swift) a ray wenderlich tutorial that goes through a simple CAAnimationGroup

Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caanimationgroup) has a great example, but you MUST specify the beginTime for each animation (otherwise each animation will run at the same time):

```
let fadeOut = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
fadeOut.fromValue = 1
fadeOut.toValue = 0
fadeOut.duration = 1
fadeOut.beginTime = 0.0

let expandScale = CABasicAnimation()
expandScale.keyPath = "transform"
expandScale.valueFunction = CAValueFunction(name: kCAValueFunctionScale)
expandScale.fromValue = [1, 1, 1]
expandScale.toValue = [3, 3, 3]
expandScale.beginTime = fadeOut.beginTime + fadeOut.duration

let fadeAndScale = CAAnimationGroup()
fadeAndScale.animations = [fadeOut, expandScale]
fadeAndScale.duration = fadeOut.duration + expandScale.duration
```